# Unable to access any HTTPS site with any Java JRE on Windows 10

Tags: networking, java, ssl, https

I am on Windows 10 18362.356.

After some system update, now it is impossible to access any TLS-enabled site with Java. Both standanlone JRE (`jre1.8.0_221`) and the JRE bundled in Android Studio 3.5.1 fails with:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

At first I thought that the `cacerts` file was faulty, but even after replacing them, the problem persists.

Wireshark shows that there is no problem with handshake and they are not blocked by firewall. 
[Screenshot of Wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7sj7.png)

Manually add certs is not effective (and not possible as none of the sites work)

`JAVA_HOME` is pointing to the correct JRE directory.

Comment: “After some system update“ - Please specify the update.

Comment: I really can not specify the update as I rarely use Android Studio recently. I am sure that it works correctly in August

Comment: So it worked 2 months ago?  What updates have you recently installed?